# Font-weight not working as expected in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-text

I am trying to set font weight '500' to text in react native but it is not working. Only fontWeight bold and normal are working.

```
{ fontWeight: '500' }
```

Any solution for this ?

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: I think it's because of the font family. Some fonts doesn't support various font weights and so, problem like that happens. The solution is to link fonts for different font weight.